# Вычисление значения математического выражения из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка, содержащая математическое выражение вида:

```
1/3+2/3
```

Есть ли модуль, который вычисляет значение таких выражений?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

С точки зрения безопасности (как уже сказал [@Batanichek](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597234) - с `eval()` нужно быть очень осторожным), производительности и гибкости лучше воспользоваться [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide):

```
In [6]: import numexpr as ne

In [7]: ne.evaluate('1/3+2/3')
Out[7]: array(1.0)

In [8]: var1=10

In [9]: var2=2

In [10]: ne.evaluate('var1**var2')
Out[10]: array(100, dtype=int32)
```

Он, кстати, быстрее для более сложных вычислений, поддерживает использование переменных, поддерживает NumPy, SciPy и т.д.

[Numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) поддерживает многопоточные вычисления (используя все доступные ядра процессора) и `VML от Intel (Vector Math Library, который интегрирован в интеловский же Math Kernel Library (MKL))`.

Пример работы с обычным ("Vanilla Python") массивом:

```
In [45]: lst = [1, 2.718281828]

In [46]: ne.evaluate('log(lst)')
Out[46]: array([ 0.,  1.])
```

с NumPy массивом:

```
In [50]: a = np.array([1, 2.718281828])

In [51]: ne.evaluate('log(a)')
Out[51]: array([ 0.,  1.])
```

Сравнение производительности с NumPy для массива, состоящего из 1го млн. элементов типа `numpy.float64`:

```
In [36]: a = np.random.rand(10**6)

In [37]: a.shape
Out[37]: (1000000,)

In [38]: len(a)
Out[38]: 1000000

In [39]: %timeit np.log(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.3 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit ne.evaluate('log(a)')
100 loops, best of 3: 5.45 ms per loop

In [41]: %timeit np.sqrt(np.sin(a)**2 + np.cos(a)**2)
10 loops, best of 3: 84.5 ms per loop

In [42]: %timeit ne.evaluate('sqrt(sin(a)**2 + cos(a)**2)')
100 loops, best of 3: 6.32 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете воcпользоваться `eval`:

```
eval('1/3+2/3')
```

Вот [тут можно почитать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Но обычно с такими функциями проблемы с безопасностью, в случае, если вы получаете строку извне (например, пользовательский ввод).

Answer (score -1):

Вроде как считается безопасным аналогом eval

```
import ast

try:
    print(ast.literal_eval(1/3+2/3))
except ValueError as err:
    print(err)
```

Только вот с данным выражением выдает ошибку

Comment: _Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression._ Передавайте строку а не результат сложения.

Comment: @mkkik кстати, действительно любопытно: ` ast.literal_eval('1+1')` работает, а `ast.literal_eval('1*1')` кидает исключение.

Comment: "It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing"

Может для него уже сложно такие вычисления сделать? :)

Comment: 1- строку передавать надо 2- с арифметическими выражениями literal_eval() не рассчитано работать. Вот [как можно, используя ast, вычислить арифметическое выражение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4279)