# Ввод выражений пользователем

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

С помощью функции `input()` во время выполнения программы пользователь может ввести значения, которое функция возвращает в виде строки. А с помощью функций преобразования типов из этих строк можно получить целое число, число с плавающей точкой и так далее. Например, `a = int(input())`.

Но вот как сделать, чтобы пользователь мог вводит функции, наподобие:

> A sin(2πƒt + Ø)

После ввода функции, над ней будут проводиться различные операции (вычисление значений, построение графиков и так далее).

Comment: Извиняюсь! Случайно удалил оставленный комментарий.

Comment: Немного не так написал, исправил текст вопроса.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/numexpr
http://newville.github.io/asteval/ например

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости от того, что вы хотите делать с введенными формулами - я бы обратил внимание на два модуля: [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/features.html) для аналитического и численного решения уравнений, построения графиков и многого другого и на [NumExpr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numexpr) для быстрого и безопасного численного вычисления введенных формул с поддержкой numpy, scipy, массивов, переменных и т.д.

[Пример использования numexpr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597291/211923)

примеры использования NumExpr c массивами Numpy :

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

In [84]: a, b = np.random.rand(2, 5)

In [85]: a
Out[85]: array([ 0.05399168,  0.85873638,  0.73317032,  0.17825897,  0.83083985])

In [86]: b
Out[86]: array([ 0.19115417,  0.66216767,  0.51021111,  0.5816862 ,  0.72958694])

In [87]: ne.evaluate('sin(a)**2 + cos(a)**2')
Out[87]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

умножение матриц:

```
In [92]: m1 = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])

In [93]: m2 = np.array([[10, 10]])

In [94]: m1
Out[94]:
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [95]: m2
Out[95]: array([[10, 10]])

In [96]: ne.evaluate('m1 * m2')
Out[96]:
array([[10, 20],
       [30, 40]], dtype=int32)
```

---

[Примеры использования SymPy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Quick-examples):

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
```

раскрываем скобки:

```
In [75]: ((x+y)**2 * (x+1)).expand()
Out[75]: x**3 + 2*x**2*y + x**2 + x*y**2 + 2*x*y + y**2
```

упрощаем выражение:

```
In [76]: simplify((x**2 - y**2) / (x - y)**2)
Out[76]: (x + y)/(x - y)
```

решение уравнения:

```
In [77]: solve(Eq(x**3 + 2*x**2 + 4*x + 8, 0), x)
Out[77]: [-2, -2*I, 2*I]
```

решение системы линейных уравнений:

```
In [78]: solve([Eq(x + 5*y, 2), Eq(-3*x + 6*y, 15)], [x, y])
Out[78]: {x: -3, y: 1}
```

аналитическое решение неопределенного интеграла:

```
In [79]: integrate(x**2 * cos(x), x)
Out[79]: x**2*sin(x) + 2*x*cos(x) - 2*sin(x)
```

или

```
In [100]: init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)

In [101]: intgrl = Integral(sin(1/x), (x, 0, 1)).transform(x, 1/x)

In [102]: intgrl
Out[102]:
 oo
  /
 |
 |  sin(x)
 |  ------ dx
 |     2
 |    x
 |
/
1
```

...

Answer (score -1):

Можно так попробовать в простом варианте

```
import math
from math import sin
from math import pi
c = eval(input('sin(2*pi*(x+y))'))
print (c)
```

Comment: В любом ответе с eval всегда стоит упоминать его небезопасность