# Преобразовать строку в sage.expression

Tags: sage

Каким образом можно преобразовать строку, содержащую представление символьного выражения к `sage.symbolic.expression.Expression`? Простое привидение типов здесь не работает.

Пока что решил эту проблему используя интерфейс `maxima`. Но, насколько я понимаю, это не сильно лучше, чем вызывать `eval`. Тем более, результат не совсем что надо.

```
sage: type(maxima("x^3 + sin(x) * erf(x)"))
sage: <class 'sage.interfaces.maxima.MaximaElement'>
```

Нужно что-то аналогичное `sympy.parsing`, только в нативный тип для sage.

Похожий вопрос: [Ввод выражений пользователем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614456/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснилось, что `sage.symbolic.expression.Expression` принадлежит к т.н. `Symbolic Ring`, который является родительским объектом для всех символьных выражений в [sage](/questions/tagged/sage).

В итоге решение сводиться к приведению типа исходного выражения:

```
sage: SR("x^3 + sin(x) * erf(x)")
x^3 + sin(x) * erf(x)
sage: type(_)
<type 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression'>
sage: diff(SR("x^4"))
4*x^3
```