# Как вызвать функцию указав ее наименование в input

Tags: python

На текущий момент пишу код, в котором есть 3 различные функции - `create`, `add` и `get`.

По условию в программу нужно передавать кортеж из 3 элементов:

```
cmd, x, y= input().split()
```

В данной строке `cmd` - должно быть наименование одной из функций, а `x`, `y` ее аргументы. Соответственно, зная `cmd` можно вызвать функции используя, к примеру, `if`-statement: `if cmd=='create': create(x, y)`.

Но, можно ли каким-нибудь образом сразу после инпута вызвать функцию вот так:

```
cmd, x, y= input().split() 
cmd(x, y)
```

В текущих условиях `cmd` это строка. Но может есть возможность определять ее как объект функции?

Причина возникновения вопроса - есть относительно схожий функционал при работе с функциями. Пример:

```
def x(num):
    print(num)
def a(x):
    x(5)
```

Comment: Речь идет о встроенной функции? Можете привести примеры функций? Если речь идет только о математических функциях то можно воспользоваться модулем [`numexpr`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597229/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Нет, в моем случае функции работают с обыкновенным словарем.

Comment: x = {'global': {'parent': None, 'vars': []}}


def create(namespace, parent):
    x[namespace] = {'parent': parent, 'vars': []}


def add(namespace, var):
    x[namespace]['vars'].append(var)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример для функций `x()` и `a()`:

```
def x(num):
    print(num)

def a(x):
    x(5)
```

---

```
In [53]: func1 = 'x'

In [54]: func2 = 'a'

In [55]: globals()[func2](globals()[func1])
5
```

PS не уверен что так можно любую функцию вызвать - со встроенными функциями так, скорее всего, не получится:

```
In [58]: globals()['max']
...
skipped
...
KeyError: 'max'
```

Встроенные функции можно достать таким образом:

```
>>> getattr(__builtins__, 'max')
<built-in function max>
>>>
```

Обернуть всё это желательно try-exept или определить функцию по умолчанию на случай если пользователь введет что-то не то.

Comment: а что если все из `__builtins__` копирнуть в `globals`?

Comment: @eri, это уже из серии грязных хаков...