# Как начать перебор массива заново?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list

Есть такой код:

```
exp = input ('Expression: ').split(' ')

for sim in exp:
     print (sim)
     if sim == '*':
         num1 = int ( exp[ exp.index(sim) - 1 ] )
         num2 = int ( exp[ exp.index(sim) + 1 ] )
         del exp[ exp.index(sim) - 1 ]
         del exp[ exp.index(sim) + 1 ]
         exp[ exp.index(sim) ] = num1 * num2
         print (exp)
```

В инпут вводится выражение вида "2 + 2 * 3 * 4". Потом эта строка разбивается на части через пробелы (`slpit(' ')`). Далее в полученном списке идёт поиск символа умножения (*). Когда он находится, удаляются его соседние значения, а сам он меняется на произведение тех значений. После этого мне нужно, что бы перебор значений начинался с самого начала, так как такой пример: "2 + 2 * 3 * 4" - моя программа превратит в "2 + 6 * 4". (Пропустит следующий символ умножения.)

Comment: Можете просто написать `eval(exp)` и все. Зачем что то придумывать

Comment: @Twiss, [я бы не стал советовать `eval`](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) ;)

Comment: А если пользователь введет выражение без пробелов и/или со скобками?  В общем, если хотите написать нормальный парсер арифметического выражения, то лучше поищите информацию в сети о том как это делать правильно или воспользуйтесь готовым решением ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597291/211923)).

Comment: @MaxU, я это делаю не для практического примениния, а для того что просто сделать) Сам себе задачки придумываю, сам их решаю.

Comment: @Don2Quixote, посмотри на мое решении данной задачи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример с рекурсией:

```
def d(input_):
    print input_
    if "*" in input_:
        smb = input_.index("*")
        lf = input_.pop(smb - 1)
        rf = input_.pop(smb)
        input_[smb - 1] = int(lf) * int(rf)
        print input_[smb - 1]
        d(input_)
    elif "+" in input_ and "*" not in input_:
        smb = input_.index("+")
        lf = input_.pop(smb - 1)
        rf = input_.pop(smb)
        input_[smb - 1] = int(lf) + int(rf)
        print input_[smb - 1]
        d(input_)
    elif len(input_) == 1:
        print input_[0]
    else:
        pass

d("2 + 2 * 3 * 4".split(" "))
# ['2', '+', '2', '*', '3', '*', '4']
# 6
# ['2', '+', 6, '*', '4']
# 24
# ['2', '+', 24]
# 26
# [26]
# 26
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот доработанный вариант пользователя [Eugene Dennis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/252825/eugene-dennis).

Я добавил возвышение в степень, деление, отнимание и скобки. Также сделал сравнение ответа моей функции и функции eval().

Но если преподносить в степень в моей функции это символ ^, а для нужно **eval** нужно писать **.

```
def isfloat(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def counter(values):
    new_values = []
    for value in values:
        if isfloat(value):
            new_values.append(float(value))
        elif value.isdigit():
            new_values.append(int(value))
        elif value in ('^', '*', '/', '+', '-', '(', ')'):
            new_values.append(value)
        else:
            print('incorrect symbol ', value)

    values = new_values

    # Проходимся по массиву и в поике скобок
    while True:
        for _ in values:
            if '(' in values:
                str_smb = values.index('(')
                end_smb = values.index(')')
                answer  = counter(values[str_smb+1: end_smb])
                values[str_smb:end_smb+1] = [answer]
        if '(' not in values:
            break

    # Проходимся по массиву и возвышаем во степень все числа
    while True:
        for _ in values:
            if '^' in values:
                smb = values.index('^')
                lf = values.pop(smb - 1)
                rf = values.pop(smb)
                values[smb - 1] = lf ** rf

        if '^' not in values:
            break

    # Проходимся по массиву и умножаем и делим
    while True:
        for smb, s in enumerate(values):
            if s == '*':
                lf = values.pop(smb - 1)
                rf = values.pop(smb)
                values[smb - 1] = lf * rf

            if s == '/':
                lf = values.pop(smb - 1)
                rf = values.pop(smb)
                values[smb - 1] = lf / rf

        if '*' not in values and '/' not in values:
            break

    # Проходимся по массиву и слаживаем и отнимаем числа
    while True:
        for smb, s in enumerate(values):
            if s == '+':
                lf = values.pop(smb - 1)
                rf = values.pop(smb)
                values[smb - 1] = lf + rf

            if s == '-':
                lf = values.pop(smb - 1)
                rf = values.pop(smb)
                values[smb - 1] = lf - rf

        if '+' not in values and '-' not in values:
            break

    if len(values) == 1:
        return values.pop(0)
    else:
        return counter(values)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #testinput = "8 / 2 * 1 + 2 ** 3 - 4 * 2 + 1 / 1" #ok 5 
    #testinput = "1 + 2 * 2 - 2 / 2" #ok 4
    #testinput = "2 ** 4.5 + 2 * 16 - 2 / 2 ** 2" #ok 54.12741699796952 
    #testinput = " 8 /  2*(   2  *2)   " #ok 16.0
    # Пришлось заменить ** на ^ поскольку функция list(testinput) разбивает строку посимвольно
    testinput = " 8 /  2*(   3  ^2)   + 2 *(2 ^ 2) + (2-1)" #ok  45.0
    evalinput = " 8 /  2*(   3  **2)   + 2 *(2 ** 2) + (2-1)"  #ok  45.0
    try:
        py_answer = eval(evalinput)
    except:
        py_answer = 'ERROR'

    # Так пример более усточевый к пользовательскому вводу
    #before:   8 /  2*(   3  ^2)   + 2 *(2 ^ 2) + (2-1)
    #after:  8/2*(3^2)+2*(2^2)+(2-1)
    print('\nbefore: ', testinput,)
    testinput = testinput.strip().replace(' ', '') 
    print('after: ', testinput, '\n')


    my_answer = counter(list(testinput) )

    if py_answer == my_answer:
        print('the answers are equal! ', my_answer)
    else:
        print('eval = ', py_answer, 'funk = ', my_answer)
```