# Вычисление значений математических выражений из формул, заданных строками в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Некий модуль содержит spisok, который надо обработать

```
spisok['data']['var1'] = "25"
spisok['data']['var2'] = "5"
spisok['formula']['calc'] = "var1 / var2"
spisok['formula']['calc2'] = "var1 * var2"
```

Приведен spisok с полями 'data' и 'formula'. Требуется написать функцию, которая бы вычисляла 'formula' и результат вычисления записывала обратно

После функции, spisok должен выглядеть так:

```
spisok = {'data': {'var1': 25, 'var2': '5'}, 'formula':{'calc': 5, 'calc2': 125}}
```

выделить поля 'formula' в отдельные строки не проблема, *только встал вопрос с преобразованием строки в формулу, где значение аргументов берутся из 'data'*

**правка** 
попробовал через .split

```
def calc_expression(test, expr):
    expression = expr.split(' ')
    return

for form in spisok['formula']
  calc_expression(spisok, form)
```

получил в результате

```
expression = ['tcq', '-', 'tcq2']
```

но потом задумался, что если формула будет более сложнее и без пробелов, то как преобразовать? например:

```
spisok['formula']['calc11'] = "(var1/var2)*var3+var4"
```

вот и решил спросить, что есть ли попроще метод, чтобы вытащить имена аргументов формулы и зафиксировать математические операции.

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597229)

Comment: Пробовал через split. 
    def calc_expr(expr):  # expr передает значение поля 'formula'
        expression = expr.split(' ')
получил expression =['var1', '/', 'var2'], но встал вопрос, как же теперь отделить символы '/*-+' от var1/var2
думал, что смогу взять поиском имена и подставить в конструкцию spisok['data'][expression[0]]  '/*-+' spisok['data'][expression[2]]
подразумевается, что вычисление и аргументов может быть множество, а не два. Ведь, заранее не знаю, сколько будет аргументов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы **динамически** считать выражения, использующие заранее неизвестные имена переменных и динамически заданные выражения функций, можно воспользоваться модулем [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html).

Пример:

```
import sympy     #  pip install sympy
from sympy import N
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (
        parse_expr,
        standard_transformations, 
        implicit_application,
        implicit_multiplication,
        implicit_multiplication_application,
        function_exponentiation)

transformations=(standard_transformations + 
                 (implicit_multiplication,
                  implicit_application,
                  function_exponentiation,
                  ))

spisok = {
    'data': {
        'var1': 25,
        'var2': 5
    },
    'formula': {
        'calc1':    'var1 / var2',
        'calc2':    'var1 * var2',
        'calc3':    'sin(var1**2) + cos(var2**2)',
        'calc4':    'sin**2 10var1*var2'
    }
}

# register_variables
sympy.symbol.var(list(spisok['data'].keys()))

# calculations
spisok['result'] = {name:N(parse_expr(f,transformations=transformations)
                                     .subs(spisok['data']))
                    for name, f in spisok['formula'].items()}
```

результат:

```
>>> print(spisok['result'])
{'calc1': 5.00000000000000, 'calc2': 125.000000000000, 'calc3': 1.16721908469734, 'calc4': 0.120087443254907}
```

PS данное решение не подверженно всяческого рода "injections" и "exploits", чего нельзя сказать о [небезопасной функции `eval()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+eval+injection+and+exploits+examples)

Comment: Ваш вариант есть желание попробовать, но пока столкнулся с проблемой установки sympy. Прав нет, чтобы что-то устанавливать. Как установлю модуль, попробую ваш вариант. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось пройти ваш вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Вы как то усложнили себе задачу, работайте с переменными и следуйте "дзен":

```
data = {'var1': 25, 'var2': 5}
def foo(var1, var2):
    return {'calc2': var1*var2, 'calc': var1/var2}
print foo(**data)
# {'calc2': 125, 'calc': 5}
```

Comment: я написал,  что топик-стартёр "усложнил", и по-людски это иначе выглядит

Comment: благодарю за помощь, через eval() получилось реализовать

Comment: @MaxU соглашусь всё таки... убрал... но получилось, что хотел

Answer (score 0):

Не лучшее решение, но можно попробовать вот так:

```
>>> for var in spisok["data"]:
>>>   vars()[var] = spisok["data"][var]

>>> for calc, expr in spisok["formula"].items():
...   print(calc + ": " + str(eval(expr)))
... 
calc: 5.0
calc2: 125
```

Потом вы просто результаты можете собрать как вам надо.
По сути - вы просто создаете глобальные переменные: `var1` и `var2` и потом через eval вычисляете формулы.

Comment: использовал globals() и все сработало через eval()
спасибо