# Как преобразовать математические примеры в строку так, чтобы при этом эта строка не была результатом этого примера в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, математика

Есть словарь с математическими примерами и я хочу написать этот пример и потом, через знак =, результат этого примера.

Вот код:

```py
from math import sqrt

dict = {
    'a': (1/(5-2*sqrt(6))) + (1/(5+2*sqrt(6))),
    'b': (2/(3*sqrt(2)+4)) - (2/(3*sqrt(2)-4)),
    'c': (6/(3+2*sqrt(3))) + (1/(3-2*sqrt(3))),
    'd': ((sqrt(11)+sqrt(6))/(sqrt(11)-sqrt(6))) + ((sqrt(11)-sqrt(6))/(sqrt(11)+sqrt(6))),
    'e': ((5+8/9) / (1+17/36) + (1+1/4)) * (5/21) + sqrt(16),
}

for i in dict.values():
    x = str(i)
    print(f'{x} = {i}')
```

Но в консоли выводится:

```
9.999999999999957 = 9.999999999999957
-7.999999999999983 = -7.999999999999983
```

и так далее...

Как сделать так, чтобы писало:

```
(1/(5-2*sqrt(6))) + (1/(5+2*sqrt(6))) = 9.999999999999957
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

У вас значениями являются **результаты выражений**, а не сами выражения...
Как вариант, выводить так:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    print(f'{k} = {v}')
```

```
a = 9.999999999999957
b = -7.999999999999983
c = -1.2264973081037431
d = 6.799999999999999
e = 5.25
```

Или выражения сделать строкими:

```
dict = {
    'a': '(1/(5-2*sqrt(6))) + (1/(5+2*sqrt(6)))',
    'b': '(2/(3*sqrt(2)+4)) - (2/(3*sqrt(2)-4))',
    'c': '(6/(3+2*sqrt(3))) + (1/(3-2*sqrt(3)))',
    'd': '((sqrt(11)+sqrt(6))/(sqrt(11)-sqrt(6))) + ((sqrt(11)-sqrt(6))/(sqrt(11)+sqrt(6)))',
    'e': '((5+8/9) / (1+17/36) + (1+1/4)) * (5/21) + sqrt(16)',
}
```

И выполнять расчет позже, выполняя с помощью [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) содержимое строк:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    print(f'{k}: {v} = {eval(v)}')
```

выведет:

```
a: (1/(5-2*sqrt(6))) + (1/(5+2*sqrt(6))) = 9.999999999999957
b: (2/(3*sqrt(2)+4)) - (2/(3*sqrt(2)-4)) = -7.999999999999983
c: (6/(3+2*sqrt(3))) + (1/(3-2*sqrt(3))) = -1.2264973081037431
d: ((sqrt(11)+sqrt(6))/(sqrt(11)-sqrt(6))) + ((sqrt(11)-sqrt(6))/(sqrt(11)+sqrt(6))) = 6.799999999999999
e: ((5+8/9) / (1+17/36) + (1+1/4)) * (5/21) + sqrt(16) = 5.25
```

Comment: `eval()` - небезопасный, может лучше [sympy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/885867/211923) воспользоваться? ;)

Comment: @MaxU написАл, а потом сам вспомнил, что слышал краем уха [про небезопасность eval](https://habr.com/ru/post/221937/)... спасибо! паределаю

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)